# AJAX History Trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have this dynamically php generated code:

```
<script>
    parent.document.title = 'Members | UrbanRanks';
    $("#cwrocket_button").click(function(){                                            
    $("#module").load("module.php?module=profile&user_url=cwrocket");
    window.history.pushState( null, null, '/cwrocket.html');
    parent.document.title = 'Cwrocket | UrbanRanks';
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    return false;
    });
</script>
<a id="cwrocket_button" href="cwrocket.html">Cwrocket</a>
```

All Ajax/jQuery functions work as expected, title and url changed when clicking the link and ignoring the href that is included just for SEO purposes.

The problem is, when I hit back or forward it only changes the url on the address bar but not the Ajax content within the module div.

I would like to see if someone could help me out implementing a code to enable back and forward without reloading the whole website.

Tried doing:

```
window.history.pushState( {site:cwrocket}, null, '/cwrocket.html');
```

And while back and forward works it reloads the whole page.

Thanks in advance for anyone that solves this headache and let me know if more code is required please.

Comment: So you are trying to populate the module div with the content you are loading in via ajax, only when the back or forward button is pressed? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, with the content that should correspond to the url.

Comment: I mean like for example clicking that link it goes to the cwrocker user page, but then when I click back the url changes back to the members.aspx (note:fake rewritten to .aspx) page, but the content and page title of cwrocker is still there.

Comment: Yeah sorry man I don't think I could help you. You should look into Angular JS which allows you to create single page applications, as that sounds what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

When you push the state, you will need to save information required to reload, then you will need to listen to the event when the back arrow is clicked:

```
window.onpopstate = function(evt) {
    // restore the previous state
}
```

That's a really general answer, but the event will have the state information you save when you push it, so you can use that to restore.

Comment: Sorry to bother you as I'm not an expert in JS but what would be a good implementation to my existing code

Comment: It's a pretty involved subject; I'd start by reading [MDN's discussion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). In general, you can pass an object as the first parameter when you call `pushstate()` that tells you what to reload in your `onpopstate` handler. Fo you, it might look something like `window.history.pushstate({loadUrl:<the url you used in the ajax load call above>}, null, '/cwrocket.html')`